# Use summarization model without training

Tags: tensorflow

The tensorflow text summarization model as described here https://github.com/tensorflow/models/tree/master/textsum requires a multi GPU architecture in order to train. My repeated attempts at training the model has resulted in memory exceptions, machine crashing for various reasons. Is the trained summarisation model available so can make use of the summarization model without the need for training? The summarization model is trained using the not free Gigaword dataset, if the trained model is not available from Google is this a factor in reason why ?

Answer (score 0):

So as far as I can tell, no one has put the trained model out there that is referenced. I too was originally running into memory issues on my macbook pro and eventually ended up using my gaming laptop which had a much better GPU.

The other option of course is to take advantage of AWS and use something like their g2.2xlarge instance. They also have their P2 instances as well, but I have not checked that out yet.

With regards to the Gigaword dataset, it simply comes down to licensing. It is not a free license from LDC and often many of the academics working on this have the dataset provided to them via their Universities or companies. I have not had luck finding it, however LDC did get back to me and advised that they do have other article datasets that have a pricetag of around $300 which is much more reasonable for those of use just trying to learn TF. That said, if you didn't want to buy anything, you can always write your own page scraper and format the data for the textsum model. https://github.com/tensorflow/models/pull/379/files

Hope this helps some.  Good luck!